# azure cli equivalent of Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I am trying to assign `Azure AD Roles` (not `Azure roles`) e.g. `Directory Writers` to a `service principal`.

The only documentation i found was using `powershell` at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0 and command `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember`

I am looking for and `azure cli` version of the same. Does it exist?

an example would also be nice, say

```
ApplicationId: 3213b664-175c-46ca-944b-247c58abcda5
Object ID: c79e0a39-44cd-475c-8bc4-1f679f85afdd
Directory Writers: 9360feb5-f418-4baa-8175-e2a00bac4301
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a built-in cmd in Azure CLI to assign AAD directory role.

Here is a workaround which uses Microsoft Graph API (reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-assign-graph#example-1-create-a-role-assignment-between-a-user-and-a-role-definition)).

```
$Body = @{ 
    "roleDefinitionId" = "{directory role id}"; 
    "principalId"      = "{service principal object id}"; 
    "directoryScopeId" = "/"
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    
$Body = $Body.Replace('"', '\"')

az rest -m post -u "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments" -b "$Body"
```

For how to get the `{directory role id}`, you can also use Microsoft Graph API [List directoryRoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with a filter.

Comment: Can you answer [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76068347/pythonic-way-to-assign-global-administrator-roles-for-azure-active-directory) which asks you to show how to run this same command in Python 3?