# Pythonic way to assign global administrator roles for Azure Active Directory

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-rbac

**What specifically needs to be changed in the Python 3 code below in order to successfully assign the Global Administrator role for an Azure Active Directory Tenant to a given service principal?**

We tried to adjust the code from [the answer to this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752779/azure-cli-equivalent-of-add-azureaddirectoryrolemember) so that it can run in Python 3, but we are getting the error below.  This has to be agnostic with respect to operating system, so we cannot use the bash code given in the other posting.  We also do not want to add a dependency on PowerShell.

And we also tried to do this with an ARM template, but @Philip pointed out that ARM templates are not allowed to assign Active Directory tenant roles.

Note that `62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10` is the role definition id for Global Administrator of an Azure Active Directory tenant.

**COMMAND AND RESULTING ERROR:**

```
C:\path\to\directory> python .\assignADRoles.py             
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: 'valid-service-principal-object-id', 'roleDefinitionId': '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10', 'directoryScopeId': '/'}

Examples from AI knowledge base:
az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits 
Get Audit log through Microsoft Graph

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/reference-index#az_rest
Read more about the command in reference docs
C:\path\to\directory>
```

Note that `valid-service-principal-object-id` refers to an actual valid service principal object id that is redacted here for security reasons.

Also note that the user running the command is also global administrator of the same Azure Active Directory tenant and is also owner of the only in-scope subscription.

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
# coding: utf-8

import subprocess
import re

ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

def callTheAPI():
  URI="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments"

  BODY={
    "principalId": "valid-service-principal-object-id",
    "roleDefinitionId": "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10",
    "directoryScopeId": "/"
  }

  assignGlobalAdminCommand='az rest --method POST --uri '+URI+' --header Content-Type=application/json --body '+str(BODY)

  proc = subprocess.Popen(assignGlobalAdminCommand,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      thetext=ansi_escape.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n'))
      print(thetext)
    else:
      break

callTheAPI()
```

Note that the python 3 requests module might be good to use here, but the supposedly working starting point in the other posting linked above uses the `az rest` cli command, so it seemed like a good idea to get a version of that working in Python 3 first before trying to put the same API call into the requests module.

**POWERSHELL VERSION THAT WORKS:**

Here are the successful results of running the `az rest` cli command using PowerShell from the answer to this other posting:

```
PS C:\path\to\directory> $Body = @{
>>     "roleDefinitionId" = "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10";
>>     "principalId"      = "valid-service-principal-object-id";
>>     "directoryScopeId" = "/"
>> } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
PS C:\path\to\directory> $Body = $Body.Replace('"', '\"')
PS C:\path\to\directory> az rest -m post -u "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments" -b "$Body"
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments/$entity",
  "directoryScopeId": "/",
  "id": "long-alpha-numeric-hash-id",
  "principalId": "valid-service-principal-object-id",
  "principalOrganizationId": "valid-ad-tenant-id",
  "resourceScope": "/",
  "roleDefinitionId": "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"
}
PS C:\path\to\directory>
```

But even though this PowerShell invocation of the `az rest` cli command works, the Python code above still gives an error.  When we paste the string result of the PowerShell `$Body = @{ "roleDefinitionId" = "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"; "principalId" = "valid-service-principal-object-id"; "directoryScopeId" = "/" } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress` command from above into the Python 3 code given above, we get the same error.

**How can this working Powershell example be translated into Python 3 starting with the Python 3 code that is given above in the OP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a Azure Active Directory role isn't possible with an ARM template.

The Azure documentation "[Tenant deployments with ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-tenant?tabs=azure-cli)", clearly states that only "*Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC)*" can be done using a tenant "roleAssignments" deployment.

For more information about Role Assignment deployments your can have a look over [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/roleassignments?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template).

---

The argument failure:

> ERROR: unrecognized arguments: 'valid-service-principal-object-id', 'roleDefinitionId': '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10', 'directoryScopeId': '/'}

in above answer is caused by an invalid formatting of the required JSON object in the body. (I've added double quotes in the working example below)

The "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/r‌​oleAssignments" endpoint only works for **user role assignments**.
The code below works with users, but fails for Applications with the error "*Objects of type Application cannot be assigned to roles.*":

```
ERROR: Bad Request({"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Objects of type Application cannot be assigned to roles.","innerError":{"date":"2023-04-24T09:25:57","request-id":"bdf05644-f7ff-49f5-b9a0-cdceac5f4242","client-request-id":"bdf05644-f7ff-49f5-b9a0-cdceac5f4242"}}})
```

*(replace 'valid-user-principal-object-id' whith the object id of the user)*

```
# coding: utf-8

import subprocess
import re

ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

def callTheAPI():
  URI="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments"

  BODY={
    "principalId": "valid-user-principal-object-id",
    "roleDefinitionId": "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10",
    "directoryScopeId": "/"
  }

  assignGlobalAdminCommand='az rest --method POST --uri '+URI+' --header Content-Type=application/json --body "'+str(BODY)+'"'

  proc = subprocess.Popen(assignGlobalAdminCommand,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      thetext=ansi_escape.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n'))
      print(thetext)
    else:
      break

callTheAPI()
```

---

Here's a working Python script to assign the "Global Administrator" role for an **App registration** (service principal (SPN)) using the

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId=62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10/members/$ref

endpoint as documented over [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-add-a-new-member-to-a-directory-role-using-roletemplateid):

*(replace 'valid-service-principal-object-id' whith the object id of the user)*

> It's the object id of the service principal you need, not the application. You can find the service principal under Enterprise Applications in Azure portal's Azure AD blade. In its Properties you'll find the object id.

```
# coding: utf-8

import subprocess
import re

ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

def callTheAPI(): URI="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId=62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10/members/\$ref" 

BODY=  {"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/valid-service-principal-object-id"}

assignGlobalAdminCommand='az rest --method POST --uri '+URI+' --header Content-Type=application/json --body "'+str(BODY)+'"'

proc = subprocess.Popen(assignGlobalAdminCommand,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
while True:
line = proc.stdout.readline()
if line:
  thetext=ansi_escape.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n'))
  print(thetext)
else:
  break

callTheAPI()
```

Comment: There's no answer to the question, it isn't possible in the way described in the post

Comment: I just updated my answer with 2 working examples of an Azure AD role assignment using "az rest" for a "user" and a "service principal".

Comment: Do you get the same results when running the same script from the Azure cloudshell when logged in as Account owner who is also subscription owner, AD global administrator and AD application administrator?  Your solution works when we run it from a laptop somewhere on the internet.  But when we run it from Azure cloudshell when logged in as Account owner who is also subscription owner, AD global administrator, and AD application administrator, the role assignments are not visible in the Active Directory's GUI in portal.azure.com.

Comment: This could be Azure deploying breaking changes because they do not test everything before moving code to production.

Comment: Indeed, there apparently is a difference between laptop and cloudshell :-/ 
I've debugged the script, and the CloudShell has difficulties in using the dollar-sign ($).
I escaped the dollar sign in my example, this is working in both environments.